# Map GPIO to 0x378 on Raspberry

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio, lpt

Is it possible to map the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Board (V2) to the memory area 0x378 ("LPT") in Raspbian, so i can use it as parallel port?

And if so, how can i achieve this? I have a faint clue, that this may be possible with C's mmap function, but I'm totally unsure about this.

Also, i am aware, that i need some bit of electronics to interface the GPIO pins, but at the moment i'm curious how to get the software "connected". (I'm planning to use SRCPD with S88 feedback)